# Is there a faster way to find a value in a multidimensional array and return all of its indexes than for(for())?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I need to find the value of a 2-dimensional array and return its indexes. For example if my searched term is in array[i][j], then I want [i, j] returned.

Naturally, I came up with this simple solution:

```
function find(str){
    for(let o = 0; o < array.length; o++){
        for(let k = 0; k < array[o].length; k++){
            if(array[o][k] == str){
                return [o, k];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to use this method a couple hundred times as part of an algorithm, and it gets quite time-costy. Is there a more efficient way?

I have created a simple full example including a 'benchmark':

```
// setup to hide foo in an array
var array = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    array.push([])
    for(let j = 0; j < 100; j++){
        if(i == 99 && j == 99) array[i].push("foo"); // intentionally hiding the searched term at the worst-case position for the algorithm of find()
        else array[i].push("bar");
    }
}

// function to find foo
function find(str){
    for(let o = 0; o < array.length; o++){
        for(let k = 0; k < array[o].length; k++){
            if(array[o][k] == str){
                return [o, k];
            }
        }
    }
}

// lets say we need to find foo 200 times
var a = window.performance.now();
for(let i = 0; i < 200; i++){
    console.log(i, find("foo")); // if you're happy and you know it, tell us what you found
}
var b = window.performance.now();

// print performance result
$('body').html((b-a) + " ms");
```

JSfiddle for the benchmark example: http://jsfiddle.net/3t0db1cq/11/

(note: in that benchmark example I searched 'foo' 200 times, so you may ask why I don't simply cache it. In reality I will search different terms, so caching will barely improve the performance. Also I intentionally did put the searched term in the worst-case position of the array for this benchmark)

Can you help me find a better algorithm for `find()`? To be fair for the performance test, re-position the searched term at the worst-case position in the array for your algorithm, if you want to compare the results.

(Target for this is websites, so all common browsers should support it)

Comment: Not in general, assuming you have no prior knowledge of ordering and distribution. You could build an index...

Comment: Can the array contain duplicates? Is the array always the same? One idea that came to mind is maybe you could loop through the multidimensional array only once and create a value -> coordinate index? Then find the coordinates from the index.

Comment: @Richrd that is a good idea, I should try that! The values are constant (at least for the runtime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that you are mapping a key (pair of integers) to a string value and you want to return the key for that value.

As you are using an array each search operation is always O(n^2) worse case, there's no "smart" way using that datastructure

As @Richrd said, you can build a reverse mapping from the string values to a pair of integers and search that. Easy way is to use a javascript Map() (hash map). Though you may want to look into a trie implementation for the string to integer map.

But this begs the question: if you are performing a lot of these reverse lookups then why store this data as a 2d-array of strings in the first place? You could save more time by storing this data as a map of strings to ints in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with SQL one way of doing this is to use sqllite. It is a very easy way to run sql in the browser.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm

Unfortunately it is not supported on all browsers so you would have to have a general idea of your audience.

Alternatively as long as all of your values are different you could reverse map your array and then search as much as you want with no cost. For instance:

```
// setup to hide foo in an array
var array = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    array.push([])
    for(let j = 0; j < 100; j++){
        if(i == 99 && j == 99) array[i].push("foo"); // intentionally hiding the searched term at the worst-case position for the algorithm of find()
        else array[i].push("bar");
    }
}

//Create your reverse mapped array. This only runs once at startup, but now allows you to 
function buildReverse(arr) {
    var reverseArr = {};
    for(let o = 0; o < arr.length; o++){
        for(let k = 0; k < arr[o].length; k++){
          reverseArr[arr[o][k]] = [o, k];
        }
    }
  return reverseArr
}
var reverseArr = buildReverse(array);
function find(str){
    if (reverseArr[str] != undefined) {
      return reverseArr[str]; 
      // or 
      //return [reverseArr[str][0], reverseArr[str][1]]
      //, etc...
    }
    return "";
}

// lets say we need to find foo 200 times
var a = window.performance.now();
for(let i = 0; i < 200; i++){
    console.log(i, find("foo")); // if you're happy and you know it, tell us what you found
}
var b = window.performance.now();

// print performance result
$('body').html((b-a) + " ms");
```